# Why does Ehcache double the size of Strings it stores in memory?

Tags: ehcache

While trying to cache some objects of few MB I observed that Ehcache doubles their size while keeping them cached.

Why does this happen? Is it an optimization? Can it be cancelled?

The following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CacheManager manager = CacheManager.newInstance();
        Cache oneCache = manager.getCache("OneCache");
        String oneMbString = generateDummyString(1024 * 1024);
        Element bigElement = new Element("key", oneMbString);
        oneCache.put(bigElement);
        System.out.println("size: "+ oneCache.getSize());
        System.out.println("inMemorySize: " + oneCache.calculateInMemorySize());
        System.out.println("size of string: " + oneMbString.getBytes().length);
    }   


    /**
    * Generate a dummy string
    *
    * @param size the size of the string in bytes.
    * @return
    */
    private static String generateDummyString(int size) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sb.append("a");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Will output:

> size: 1
>
> inMemorySize: 2097384
>
> size of string: 1048576

PS: The **ehcache.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect" maxBytesLocalHeap="512M">
    <cache name="OneCache"
           eternal="false"
           overflowToDisk="false"
           diskPersistent="false"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
        <sizeOfPolicy maxDepth="10000" maxDepthExceededBehavior="abort"/>
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

Comment: Try using a unicode character in your generateDummyString function.

Comment: @sgmoore Just tried it, nothing changed. Also as you see I check both the size of the string in bytes and the in memory size, therefore if the size of the string in bytes would have been doubled I would have noticed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in Java use 2-byte characters.  Ehcache is not doubling the size.  When you call toBytes(), you get the encoded bytes (in this case the default UTF-8 encoding is used).  This is why you see the difference.

Comment: Thank you Martin Serrano, I was missing that point. Doing a call toBytes() and then storing the item solved the problem.